# Rails migration delete row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, delete-row, migrate

I'm trying to run a migration to delete two rows in the database. Here's the migration file ...

```
class RemoveMenuItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    MenuItem.delete(name: "Validation Settings")
    MenuItem.delete(name: "Identifier Lookup")
  end

  def down
    MenuItem.create(name: "Validation Settings", type: "MenuItem", actionable_item_id: 89, actionable_items_count: 0, sequence: 20)
    MenuItem.create(name: "Identifier Lookup", type: "MenuItem", actionable_item_id: 89, actionable_items_count: 0, sequence: 30)
  end
end
```

... but I'm getting this error ...

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
LINE 1: ...ERE "actionable_items"."type" IN ('MenuItem') AND "id"."name...
                                                             ^
: DELETE FROM "actionable_items" WHERE "actionable_items"."type" IN ('MenuItem') AND "id"."name" = 'Validation Settings'/Users/kweihe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `async_exec'
```

Comment: Aren't migration used for modifying database schema? And you are actually dealing with database data. For this, I think you should use schema file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
class RemoveActionableItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class ActionableItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :actionable_item, :name, :sequence, :type
  end
  def up
    validation_settings = MenuItem.find_by_name("Validation Settings")
    identifier_lookup = MenuItem.find_by_name("Identifier Lookup")
    compliance = InsightReportMenuItem.find_by_name("Compliance")
    validation_settings.delete unless validation_settings.nil?
    identifier_lookup.delete unless identifier_lookup.nil?
    compliance.delete unless compliance.nil?
  end

  def down
    MenuItem.create :name => "Validation Settings", :type => "MenuItem"
    MenuItem.create :name => "Identifier Lookup", :type => "MenuItem"
    InsightReportMenuItem.create :name => "Compliance", :type => "InsightReportMenuItem"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Deletes require an identified record to work. Try this:

```
 def up
      MenuItem.find_by(name: "Validation Settings").delete
      ....
```

I agree with the commenter though - this doesn't seem like something you necessarily want in your migrations. Probably better in a seed file.